# libtool: undefined symbols not allowed in i686-pc-mingw32 shared

Tags: c++, mingw, libtool, mingw-w64

I'm using autotools as build system for a library of mine. Recently library is ported to Windows. Library compiles and links successfully though I encountered a strange error. There is only static libraries after configure and make. Evertything looks OK except a warning from `libtool`:

```
libtool: undefined symbols not allowed in i686-pc-mingw32 shared
```

I have exported all symbols for Windows machines by this code:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#    ifdef DLL_EXPORT
#        define LIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#    else
#        define LIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#    endif
#endif
#ifndef _WIN32
#    define LIBRARY_API
#endif
```

And in every single definition I have:

```
class LIBRARY_API myClass {
// ...
```

**Notes**:
**Operating System**: Windows 8 x86_64
**Compiler suite**: MinGW x86_64, MSYS x86

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your `configure.ac`, make sure your libtool initialization looks like:

```
LT_INIT([win32-dll])
```

Also, you need to pass `-no-undefined` flag to libtool in your `Makefile.am`. This flag disables the warning you are getting:

```
libexample_la_LDFLAGS = -no-undefined
```

More details about this in the [LT_INIT documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/LT_005fINIT.html).